# Создание динамических элементов в AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Как создавать динамические элементы в *AngularJS*, если шаблон приходит с сервера в *JSON* формате, в данном случае `$scope.form`, к примеру:

```
<body ng-app="MyMod" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="el in from">
        <my-build-form></my-build-form>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    angular.module('MyMod', []).directive('myBuildForm', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<{{el.tagName}} type=text>'
        }
    }).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.from = [
            {'tagName': 'input', name: 'login', attrs: { max: 100, min: 30 }},
            {'tagName': 'input', name: 'pwd', attrs: { max: 60, min: 30 }}
        ]
    })
</script>
```

И ещё одни вопрос: как можно было отрисовать атрибуты, что-то вроде такого:

```
'<' + element.tagName +  + {{ for (attr in element.attrs) это записать как строчку 'attr = element.attrs[attr]' }} + '>'
```

Comment: что именно приходит с сервера в json?

Comment: если не ошибаюсь значение темплейта может быть функцией которая возвращает строку

Comment: "elements": [
      {
        "tagName": "input",
        "attrs": {
          "type": "number",
          "max": 158,
          "min": 6,
          "require": true
        }
      },
      {
        "tagName": "input",
        "attrs": {
          "type": "number",
          "max": 91,
          "min": 3,
          "require": false
        }
      },}

Comment: в пост это добавь

Comment: добавляю таким способом template: '<{{el.tagName}} type=text>', оно тупо выводит такой тест '<input type=text>', а не элемент, а мне нужно чтобы вставлялся элемент дом, мне просто потом нужно добавить ng-model, чтобы ангуляр спасил, если буду делать через jquery, то angular не будет видеть эту модель, тк ангулярь парсит и отображает до jquery

Comment: можешь [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) с примером сделать?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/vTDObJOQBDLUkyLtVvpO?p=preview

Comment: ну просто вывести можно вот так: http://plnkr.co/edit/uCfvPwzAcUozJzi5t5ET?p=preview

Comment: спасибо) я почему то думал что нужно отрисовать это в темплейте срзу

Comment: но так не будет `ng-model` работать. В темплейте можно, но только если значения аттрибутов, а не сам атрибуты или элемент

Comment: вот, а если делать через template, то будет, можно как то это объединить ?

Comment: можно, если не срочно - попозже напишу вариант

Comment: хорошо,спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ангуляр предоставляет сервис [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile), который позволяет скомпилировать строку или html элемент в шаблон, который потом можно связать со скопом.

В вашем случае - собираем строку, отправляем ее в сервис, и связываем с нужным скопом.

Например так:

```js
angular.module('MyMod', [])
  .directive('myBuildForm', ['$compile',
    function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element) {
          element.append('<' + scope.el.tagName + ' type="text" ng-model="el.' + scope.el.name + '" ' + scope.el.attrs.toString() + '>');
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
      };
    }
  ])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.from = [{
      'tagName': 'input',
      name: 'login',
      attrs: ['max=100 min=30 required']
    }, {
      'tagName': 'input',
      name: 'pwd',
      attrs: ['max=60 min=30 required']
    }]
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyMod" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="el in from">
    <div>{{el.name}} = {{el[el.name]}}</div>
    <my-build-form></my-build-form>
  </div>

</div>
```

**UPDATE:** пример с формой.

```js
angular.module('MyMod', [])
  .directive('myBuildForm', ['$compile',
    function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element) {
          element.append('<' + scope.el.tagName + ' type="text" ng-model="el.' + scope.el.name + '" ' + scope.el.attrs.toString() + '>');
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
      };
    }
  ])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.from = [{
      'tagName': 'input',
      name: 'login',
      attrs: ['ng-maxlength="5" ng-minlength="1" required']
    }, {
      'tagName': 'input',
      name: 'pwd',
      attrs: ['ng-maxlength="5" ng-minlength="1" required']
    }, ];

    $scope.check = function($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();
      if(!$scope.myForm.$invalid){
        console.log('success');
      }else{
        console.log('invalid');
      }
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyMod" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<form action="" name="myForm" novalidate>
      <div ng-repeat="el in from">
      <my-build-form></my-build-form>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="check($event)">Confirm</button>
    </form>
    <div ng-show="login">
      login : {{login}}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div ng-show="pwd">
      password : {{pwd}}
    </div>
    
    {{myForm.$invalid}}

</div>
```

Comment: я обернул div с ng-repeat в форму, и форма не видит модели, у ангуляра есть своя валидация, и получается, что форма всегда невалидна, приходится писать функцию которая фалидирует форму. К примеру если написать <button ng-disabled="form.$invalid">, то такой подход не будет работать, и приходится писать <button on-click="checkFrom()">

Comment: @KhoteyVitaliy, сделай конкретный пример с формой, что ты пробовал и что не получается. По примеру который в посте - все работает

Comment: <form action="" name="myForm" novalidate>
      <div ng-repeat="el in from">
      <my-build-form></my-build-form>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="check($event)">Confirm</button>
    </form> приходится руками валидировать форму через функцию :$scope.check = function ($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
          
         if ($scope.login && $scope.pwd) {
           alert('success');
         }
         
         if (!$scope.login && !$scope.pwd) {
           alert('invalid form');
         }
         
        }

Comment: @KhoteyVitaliy, код добавляй в пост, и в идеале сразу планкер с ним :)

Comment: Вижу что в комментариях плохо писать код) http://plnkr.co/edit/K03BBlB6Y3fLb9IRSAvP?p=info

Comment: @KhoteyVitaliy, но в пост все равно надо добавить, чтобы было видно тем кто после придет

Comment: @KhoteyVitaliy, вроде все работает, посмотри отредактированный ответ

Comment: спасибо, работает

Comment: @KhoteyVitaliy, сравните мой код и ваш, я думаю должно стать понятнее, что не так было.