# Angular, форма не отрабатывает, так как её html код с сервера append

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Такая проблема, *<form>* загружаю *get* запросом, приходит *html* код и я его `append` в *dom*. Но она не отрабатывает(submit). Как её, скажем так, привязать к ангуляру или определить её, чтобы работало?
Форма, только сразу вставленная в страницу(для теста) работает.

```
var promise = mainService.getRegisterForm();
if($location.absUrl() == absUrl + 'register'){
            promise.then(showRegisterForm);
        }
function showRegisterForm(data){
        elReg.append(data.data);
    }


<form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="mainCtrl" novalidate>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
                        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-radio active" onclick="$('#infoBlockReg').html($(this).find('.info-block').html())">
                            <input type="radio" checked name="type" id="entity" value="entity"> {{ $data['user']['type']['entity']['title'] }}
                            <span class="hidden info-block">
                                Вы регистрируетесь как физическое лицо
                            </span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0">
                        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-radio" onclick="$('#infoBlockReg').html($(this).find('.info-block').html())">
                            <input type="radio" name="type" id="individual" value="individual"> {{ $data['user']['type']['individual']['title'] }}
                            <span class="hidden info-block">
                                Вы регистрируетесь как представитель юридического лица, ИП, КФХ
                            </span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="text-center" id="infoBlockReg">
                    Вы регистрируетесь как физическое лицо
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <p>{{ $data['user']['type']['entity']['header'] }}</p>

                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="entity">
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('first') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="first" class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 control-label">{{ $data['user']['type']['entity']['fillable']['first'] }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-7">
                            <input ng-model="commentData.first" type="text" class="form-control" name="first" placeholder="Укажите Ваше Имя" value="{{ old('first') }}" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                            @if ($errors->has('first'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    {{ $errors->first('first') }}
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('last') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="last" class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 control-label">{{ $data['user']['type']['entity']['fillable']['last'] }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-7">
                            <input ng-model="commentData.last" type="text" class="form-control" name="last" placeholder="Укажите Вашу Фамилию"  value="{{ old('last') }}" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                            @if ($errors->has('last'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    {{ $errors->first('last') }}
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 control-label">{{ $data['user']['type']['entity']['fillable']['email'] }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-7">
                            <input ng-model="commentData.email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="example@example.com" value="{{ old('email') }}" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    {{ $errors->first('email') }}
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('curator') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="curator" class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 control-label">{!! $data['user']['type']['entity']['fillable']['curator'] !!}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-7">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="curator" placeholder="" value="{{ old('curator') }}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                            @if ($errors->has('curator'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    {{ $errors->first('curator') }}
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{--<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('check') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" value="Получить код">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-7 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-offset-0">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="check" placeholder="" value="{{ old('check') }}">
                        </div>
                        @if ($errors->has('check'))
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    {{ $errors->first('check') }}
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>--}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" value="Подтвердить">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <p style="text-align: justify; ">{!! $data['user']['type']['entity']['footer'] !!}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: без [mcve] нельзя ничего сказать, добавляй свой код в вопрос

Comment: И чем Вам поможет этот кусочек кода?

Comment: этот конечно не поможет, нужен код ангуляра: как получается эта форма, как она вставляется, и разметка html к которой этот код применяется

Comment: @Grundy отправил

Comment: `<form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="mainCtrl" novalidate>` - это форма которую ты получаешь? или это уже существующая? что такое `elReg`? и добавь пример `mainService.getRegisterForm`

Comment: Зачем? Там всё работает. Форма приходит, форма добавляется в dom и я её вижу. Но она не отправляет свои данные на сервер, не отрабатывает submit и angular не добавляет её например ng-form-dirty он её как бы не видет
Да это форма, которую я получаю
elReg это элемент куда вставляется форма

Comment: Мне нужно видеть каким образом ты делаешь запрос, `$http` или каким-нибудь левым способом. `elReg.append` - не нужен

Comment: почитайте про $compiler https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler

Comment: @Chikiro, скорее всего тут можно обойтись без него

Comment: @Chikiro, хотя да, именно тут похоже все-таки нельзя

Comment: @Grundy, http да

Comment: @unrealisted, [похожий вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469496/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проще всего перенести все в директиву

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.register = true;
  }).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.list = [];
    $scope.submit = function() {
      if ($scope.text) {
        $scope.list.push($scope.text);
        $scope.text = '';
      }
    }
  }).directive('registerForm', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'some/path/to/form'
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <register-form ng-if="register"></register-form>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="some/path/to/form">
    <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
      Enter text and hit enter:
      <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
      <pre>list=@{{list|json}}</pre>
    </form>
  </script>
</div>
```